# Day-O clock not starting by itself on restarting Mac

Tags: calendar, menu-bar

I am using  [Day-O](https://shauninman.com/archive/2011/10/20/day_o_mac_menu_bar_clock) as the clock on the menu bar in place of the default clock. After installation I have checked "Launch Day-O at login" but whenever I restart my mac Day-O does not start by itself. I have to manually double click it to start.

I have also added Day-O under Login Items under "System Preferences". But still no luck.

Can you let me know how can I make Day-O to start at Login.

Environment

Mac OS - 10.12.6
Day-O - Version 2.0 (21)

Comment: Have you contacted the developer of this application and asked for help in getting it to work correctly?

Comment: When you added the app to login items are you sure that window was unlocked? I can add items with the page locked but it doesn't take unless I unlock it.

Comment: @john Can you post this as an answer so that I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to system preferences and click on Users and Groups. Then click on box login items. This brings up a list of apps to start up when you login. You can add your app to this list but be sure to unlock the page. Click the padlock icon in lower left of window. You can add an app without unlocking but it won't take effect unless you unlock that option.

Comment: Unlocking this pane is unnecessary and does not change any functionality of the Login Items list.

Comment: it does for me.

Comment: I don't see a padlock under Login Items